# Why does Process in dart need arguments separated in a list after every space?

Tags: flutter, shell, dart, process

Why does `Process.start` need arguments separated in a list after every space? For example according to the docs https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process/start.html
to grep a main in test.dart, we need to do

`var process = await Process.start('grep', ['-i', 'main', 'test.dart']);`

Won't this be a better way?

`var process = await Process.start('grep', ['-i main','test.dart','-other options']);`

Comment: The latter would perform the equivalent of running `grep "-i main" test.dart "-other options"` in your command-line shell.  Note that it will not do what you want, and that's not up to Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What David Penkowoj says is correct but I want to add some more details to his answer.

The reason is that this is actually how programs gets its arguments, as a List of Strings. You can see this if you make this basic program:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print(args);
}
```

We can then execute the program using a terminal:

```
>dart stackoverflow.dart first second third
[first, second, third]
```

As you can see, our terminal sends each argument into our program as a separate `String` value in our argument list.

But what if we want our arguments to be a single one? Well, in most terminals we can use `"` (see the comma between "second" and "third" is gone):

```
>dart stackoverflow.dart first "second third"
[first, second third]
```

But hey where did the `"` go? Well, this is just how our terminal (in my case CMD) does interpret my input and CMD uses `"` to signal if multiple arguments should be together even if separated with spaces.

If we want to send `"` in as arguments, we need to escape the `"` character so CMD knows it should see it as part of the argument:

```
>dart stackoverflow.dart first "\"second third\""
[first, "second third"]
```

So what does this has to do with `Process.start`? Well, the reason is that `Process.start` does not start your application though a terminal (e.g. CMD). Instead, it start the program directly and there are therefore not any interpretation of the arguments. Instead, the arguments are sent directly to the program being executed.

And as you can see, the standard behavior of a terminal (like CMD) does separate arguments separated with spaces. So if you want to start a program like you do from a terminal, you will also need to separate the arguments as individual `String` objects in a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the way programs parse command line arguments.

For humans, it is plausible that after an "option type" (-i) should come an "option value" (main). For computers it's not. They just parse the individual strings and decide how to use them, depending on how the programmer used the information.

It would be inconsistent, and inherently unsolvable (or at least too complicated) for the computer to be able to decide when to have arguments be split on a space or not.